# 1 required argument(s) expected, but 0 found

Tags: dart, arguments, flutter, flutter-layout, dart-pub

i'm new to using flutter and i have been stuck for over a week with the above error. i searched this forum for possible solution but not found. this is the code below, kindly assist with correction/advice. thanks in advance:

=================================================================

```
class AfterSplash extends StatelessWidget {

    @override

    Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return new Scaffold( <=1 required argument(s) expected, but 0 found. on the open bracket sign
        appBar: new AppBar(
        title: new Text('Test'),
          ),
          backgroundColor: Colors.black38,

        body: 
        new ImageCarousel(
        <ImageProvider>[
          new NetworkImage(
              'http://wallpaper-gallery.net/images/images/images-2.jpg'),
          new NetworkImage(
              'http://wallpaper-gallery.net/images/images/images-10.jpg'),
          new NetworkImage(
              'http://wallpaper-gallery.net/images/images/images-4.jpg'),
        ],
        interval: new Duration(seconds: 5),
        ),


        bottomNavigationBar: new BottomNavigationBar(
          currentIndex: 0,
          items: [
            new BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: const Icon(Icons.local_movies),
              title: new Text('VIDEOS'),
            ),

            new BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: const Icon(Icons.camera_alt),
              title: new Text('PICTURES'),
            ),

            new BottomNavigationBarItem(
              icon: const Icon(Icons.contacts),
              title: new Text('BOOKING'),
            ),
          ]    
      )
    );  

  }

}
```

Comment: Yes @daniel, I'm using dart2 but ran into same issue while running carousel pro package before using image carousel. Same error persists even when I remove carousel packages completely

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Dart2?

Assuming that [this](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/image_carousel) is the package you are using for the ImageCarousel, this package does not work with Dart2.

I replicated your code in Dart2 without the ImageCarousel widget and it worked fine.

Comment: @Mannie It looks like a problem with de flutter installation. Try to delete and reinstall the flutter folder. Source: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/21319